# How to use the pool connections set up with django-postgrespool2 when querying the database?

Tags: django, postgresql, connection-pooling

I have just set up `django-postgrespool2` for creating a connection pool between my Django and PostgreSQL database. I followed the readme guide [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-postgrespool2/) on how to install and config it. It works now and I can run my project with `django-postgrespool2`.

However, here comes my question. How do I verify that the pool connections are being used when I query the database? What code should be used when connecting to the database, is it any different or can I use the same code as before?

My database settings in settings.py, I have set the database engine to `django_postgrespool2`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_postgrespool2', 
        'NAME': env_config.get('DB_NAME'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=myappdjango'
        },
        'USER': env_config.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env_config.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env_config.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': env_config.get('DB_PORT')
    }
}
```

My settings for `django-postgrespool2`:

```
DATABASE_POOL_CLASS = 'sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool'

DATABASE_POOL_ARGS = {
    'max_overflow': 10,
    'pool_size': 5,
    'recycle': 300
}
```

Code example of how I connect and query the database:

```
def paginateData(self, paginationData, search):
        sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM tablex "
        sqlWhere = self.buildCTPagianteSqlWhere(search)
        sqlOrderBy = "ORDER BY name "
        sqlPagination = "LIMIT %s OFFSET %s;"
        sql = sqlSelect + sqlWhere + sqlOrderBy + sqlPagination
        sqlParams = self.buildCTPaginateParams(paginationData, search)

        cursor = db.cursor("mydatabase", sql, sqlParams)
        dataResult = cursor.connect()

        return dataResult
```

Does the following db code `cursor = db.cursor("mydatabase", sql, sqlParams)` actually utilize the pool connections? Or does the db code have to be written differently with `django-postgrespool2`?

Output sample from Django:

```
2021-03-08 08:35:50:DEBUG:z.pool: new connection
2021-03-08 08:35:50:DEBUG:z.pool: retrieved from pool
March 08, 2021 - 08:35:50
Django version 2.2.5, using settings 'myapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
2021-03-08 08:35:52:DEBUG:z.pool: new connection
2021-03-08 08:35:52:DEBUG:z.pool: retrieved from pool
[08/Mar/2021 08:35:53] "GET /administration/getlineandcellname?lineid=14&cellid=58 HTTP/1.1" 200 77
[08/Mar/2021 08:35:53] "GET /checkuser/?username=tobbe HTTP/1.1" 200 3
2021-03-08 08:35:53:DEBUG:z.pool: returned to pool
[08/Mar/2021 08:35:54] "GET /administration/getlineandcellname?lineid=14&cellid=58 HTTP/1.1" 200 77
[08/Mar/2021 08:35:56] "GET /administration/getlineandcellname?lineid=14&cellid=58 HTTP/1.1" 200 77
2021-03-08 08:35:57:DEBUG:z.pool: retrieved from pool
[08/Mar/2021 08:35:57] "GET /checkuser/?username=tobbe HTTP/1.1" 200 3
2021-03-08 08:35:57:DEBUG:z.pool: returned to pool
[08/Mar/2021 08:35:58] "GET /administration/getlineandcellname?lineid=14&cellid=58 HTTP/1.1" 200 77
```

I can see information in the Django output such as `retrieved from pool`. So it does seem to work. However, I want help with verifying if I am using the db connection pool correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the settings log_connections and log_disconnections in your postgresql.conf, and check that the database is logging fewer connections that your code is checking out of and back in to the pool.